# Python Lowercase and Uppercase String

Tags: python, string, uppercase, lowercase

Is there a way to convert a string to a sequence of uppercase and lowercase letters?

For example, "Kilometers" → "KiLoMeTeRs".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a = 'Kilometers'

print(''.join([char.upper() if i%2==0 else char.lower() for i, char in enumerate(a)]))
```

result = 'KiLoMeTeRs'

Answer (score 2):

A more esoteric way:

```
>>> a = 'Kilometers'
>>> "".join("".join(i) for i in zip(a[::2].upper(), a[1::2].lower()))
'KiLoMeTeRs'
```

or using @lenik's more concise form:

```
>>> "".join(a+b for a, b in zip(a[::2].upper(), a[1::2].lower()))
```